# rails 3.1 windows new project js issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just installed rails 3.1 and generated a test application to take the changes for a spin. But after updating creating the pages controller and updating the routes to point ot paged#index I get this:

```
Showing D:/Projects/randomTest/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

["ok","(function() {\n\n}).call(this);\n"]

  (in D:/Projects/randomTest/app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>RandomTest</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your layout file looks fine, would you mind posting the contents of your application js file and the pages.js.coffee?

Comment: The are the default generated files, I made no modifications to them

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

So I managed to figured it out, looked like I had to install execjs gem, a simple:

```
gem install execjs
```

Did the trick !